# Is it necessary to care about calling convention of a function that is not exported from dll

Tags: c, dll, calling-convention, stdcall

I am currently working on a project that involves creating some DLL libraries with `C` that will be shipped to customers. The DLL exports some functions and all exported functions use the `__stdcall` calling convention. The library also contains some functions that are not exported but are used by the exported functions. Is it necessary to care about the calling convention of these local functions? Can I leave the calling convention of the local functions to the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to worry about calling conventions of internal functions. Yes, you can leave them as they are.

Calling convention is an instruction for a compiler. You need to worry about that only if you want to call your function "manually", e.g. from Assembly or other languages.

Your DLL is already compiled and internal functions are linked.